# Reopen window closed by mistake in Talend

Tags: eclipse, talend

In Talend Open Studio, if you have the Components view open in a separate window (ie. rather than docked), and hit Esc to cancel an auto-completion menu (such as while editing some code for a Java component), the whole window will close, even if there is more than one view in that window. This is really annoying and a time waster.

Does anyone know of a way to either...

1. Disable the Esc key from closing the window or
2. Quickly restore the window just closed (and all the views that were in it)?

Since Talend is built on top of Eclipse, perhaps some of you Eclipse experts may know how to do this in Eclipse, which would probably apply as well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way of disabling the `ESC` shortcut in Eclipse or Talend. However, what you can do, is assign a shortcut key for the Component view. See attached picture.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The major trouble is that I usually have multiple views in the same window, so they all disappear, not just the component tab.